# Javascript post data from included file to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a file index.asp where i include files

```
<!--#include file="/header.asp"-->
<!--#include file="/middle.asp"-->
<!--#include file="/center.asp"-->
<!--#include file="/bottom.asp"-->
<!--#include file="/footer.asp"-->
```

Each file has it own div equal to it name

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

middle.asp file have script

```
function SendFiltered() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Filtered.asp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".center").html(data)
        }
    });
};
```

So i need from middle.asp (called from index.asp) insert Post data to center.asp div

But `$(".center").html(data)` cant do this.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you include your jQuery code inside

```
$( document ).ready(){

 });
```

the action will run once the DOM is loaded